# How to make Crosswalk expansion file?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I'm using crosswalk in ionic project.

The app's size is too big for Google Play (50mb limit). How can I make a expansion file for Crosswalk runtime library?

I have read some post like : https://lists.crosswalk-project.org/pipermail/crosswalk-dev/2015-August/002968.html and https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/pull/3281 but can't get anything from there.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is under implementation, you can track it from https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4726